# How do I build my source code using webpack at GAE service deploying stage?

Tags: google-app-engine

`GAE` standard environment.

My thinking and the workflow like below:

Deploy `GAE` service to GCP => build my source code from `.ts` to `.js` => start the node.js server

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-compile-after-deploy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/main.js",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack",
    "deploy:dev": "gcloud app deploy ./app.dev.yaml",
    "deploy:prod": "gcloud app deploy ./app.prod.yaml"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

I put all node modules to `dependencies` because `cloud build` uses `npm install --production` command to install dependencies.

After I deployed my `GAE` service to `GCP` and try to access my application.

The `stackdriver logs` show me an error like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/srv/dist/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

So I think `npm run build` probably failed.

Is that possible to compile my source code using `webpack` at the `GAE` deploying stage?

If the answer is yes. How do I solve this error? thanks.

**update**

I can deploy and run my application successfully by below workflow:

build source code from `.ts` to `.js`, generate `./dist` directory => run `gcloud app deploy` will upload `./dist` directory to `GAE` container => run `npm start` to start application.

So, the only difference between these two workflows is when to build the source code.

build the source code locally or build the source code at cloud build staging(before starting the application)

Comment: @DanCornilescu the update part is not anwser.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

This takes two steps

1. building the contributed npm build step image
2. using the the
   npm build step to run npm commands

**Creating then NPM build-step-image**

I've customized the [build image in a fork](https://github.com/tonymet/cloud-builders/tree/master/npm) to use node-alpine

```
git clone git@github.com:tonymet/cloud-builders.git
cd npm 
# this will create the npm image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/npm:latest
gcloud builds submit .
```

**Add the build step to your cloudbuild.yaml, and submit manually**

Now create a cloudbuild.yaml in your project which will do the webpack
steps:

```
- name: "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/npm:latest"
  args: ["run" , "test"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "app-complete.yaml"]
timeout: "1600s"
```